# Can I add <br> tag on all images that are displayed on the page?

Tags: php, html

This is the part of the code that I'm using to display content from rss.php feed.

```
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p><a style="color:#000;text-decoration:none;" href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'"></>'.$description.'</p>';
```

The problem is that `.$description.` contains image + text and I'm ending with wording next to images. Is there any way I can add `<br>` tag on all images that are displayed on the page? I don't have access to rss.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
 $description = str_replace("</img>","</img><br/>",$description);
```

Comment: Nice brain!  I was thinking along the lines of CSS and styling, but your answer is actually correct.

Comment: This answered not correct.img tag have * attribute !! Use `preg_replace`. ;)

Comment: Thanks lads, I noticed that code for images looks like that: <img src="http://www.website.com/images1.jpg"/> so  $description = str_replace("</img>","</img><br/>",$description); is not working. Could someone update the code given by Layton Everson? :)

Comment: try this:

str_replace("/>","/><br/>",$description);

Comment: Sorted by Layton Everson! Cheers mate :)

Comment: Any time Kris,  my answer below is how I would accomplish this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Add a css class to your feed descriptions that looks like this:

Add to page CSS:

```
.feedItem img {
    clear: right;
    display: block;
}
```

And add **class="feedItem"** to p tag:

```
echo '<p class="feedItem"><a style="color:#000;text-decoration:none;" href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'"></>'.$description.'</p>';
```

Comment: You can also add some padding around the images to make it look better. And the clear:right is not required either...  Just making the image display as block will move the text below it.